# My logo is great on the desktop, but on mobile it is too big

Tags: html, css

I know this is a simple fix, but I am clueless on how to actually fix the problem. It's weird. On the desktop version, my logo is smaller than I want it to be because on the mobile it gets way too big.

Here is my css code:

```css
#logo{
    height:380%;
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```

And here is my meta tag for other devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I also researched a bit and saw that I need an `@media`? Also here is the picture:

[image]

Here is my full css code as requested:

```
        .navbar-text pull-left{
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar-text p{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar{
    border: 0px;
}

#logo{
    height:500%;
    margin-top: -35px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) { 
#logo {
     height:150%; // Change this value
     margin-top: -35px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can implement the equivalent of *max-font-size* with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)</s>

The idea is relatively simple.

1. You set the font size to `20vw` - read about `vw` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vw) - since it's
   a logo.
2. you overwrite the `font-size` with a fixed size once the viewer size
   exceeds a certain point - `450px` in my example below.

The end result is that your **font will adjust to the screen size and will be responsive**.

**Working example:**

```css
#logo {
  font-size: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  #logo {
    font-size: 83px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">"Quotin"</div>
```

**Edit:**

I just realized your **logo is an image.**

**I trimmed the extra empty space off your logo in Photoshop** because that's a lot easier than messing with negative margins in this case.

This should work on both mobile and desktop screens and be responsive **without needing media queries**

**Working Example:**

```css
#logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.quotin.co"><img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/dTt4xv/8DL1n.png"></a>
```

Comment: Will this work with it: `<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.quotin.co"><img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="img/Quotin_q.png"></a>`

Comment: I edited the answer and added another example @SarahJ.Smith. I wasn't aware your logo is an image.

Comment: Oh this made everything too big on both lol... EDIT: Is it because I'm using bootstrap?

Comment: That probably happened because I am using a different version of your logo in my example. The one I have in my example is smaller because I used Photoshop to remove all the extra empty space around the logo.  You should edit your logo to reduce all of this extra space. I put a red border along the edges of your image. Your logo is in the middle but the rest of the space between the logo and the border is actually [a part of your image.](https://image.ibb.co/fmOJqF/Capture.png)

Comment: I actually fixed it with a little bit of your help, Thank you so much! @Ihazkode

Comment: @SarahJ.Smith Awesome! I'm glad you sorted it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would replace 380% by a size in either pixel or rem.
Mobile screens have nowadays very high pixel density. Here is a good example on how to make a responsive logo https://getflywheel.com/layout/css-sprites-make-your-logo-responsive/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Media Query is what you should be looking for. Assuming that your desired mobile width is 640px, put the following in your CSS to display it differently on mobile view.

```
@media (min-width: 640px) { 
    #logo {
         height:150%; // Change this value to adjust logo size
         margin-top: -35px; // Change this value to vertically move your logo.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to move it to? If you want to move it to the top, change the value of `margin-top: -35px`.

Comment: I want to move it up on the mobile version. How would I do that?

Comment: See my updated original post, you then would need to change the value of `margin-top` something closer to 0.

Comment: Ahh im sorry. Everytime I add that code, my logo disappears. Unless I'm not suppose to add both logo css code? I have my original one and then yours.

Comment: Can you post your full code in your original post again? You only need to add my code to the bottom in your css file while keeping your original code in tact.

Comment: Oh wait! I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all good.  Just change `min-width` to `max-width`, and you're all set.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #logo { height: 150%; };
}
```

Right now, what you are saying is:

- `#logo { height: 500%; }` - Give the logo a height of 500%.
- `@media ..(min-width: 640px) {#logo {height: 150%;} }` - If the screen size is at **minimum** 640px wide (or wider...), let the height be 150%.

I'm surprised nobody noticed this before.